# Order query by input

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I do have a query in a table called article.

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
                    ->from('article a')
                    ->WhereIn('a.name', $input)
                    ->execute();

$input = array(
    0 => Tomato,
    1 => Apple,
    2 => Banana
);
```

I find all inputs. But the output of the query is a different order: Apple, Banana, Tomato. I want the order like the input? How can I realize it?

Comment: +1, interesting question... no idea though. I doubt you can do that in DQL.

Comment: Check out [this](https://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/ffac5e58feac9ef9?pli=1) thread, it's not a solution, but a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I used something like this in a project that had MySQL as the RDBMS:

```
$ids = array(2,9,3,64,23,38); // example IDs
$qry->addOrderBy("FIND_IN_SET(q.id, '" . implode(",", $ids) . "')");
```

This was in a project where the values in `$ids` were known and trusted, and came from a Xapian search query which was ordered by relevance to the search term.  Using `FIND_IN_SET()` enabled me to retrieve the right documents and present them in order of the relevance on the search results page.

*Disclaimer: I don't know the level of support for this function, but it suited me fine at the time :-)*